# Odoo8 TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: odoo-8

Good night,

i'm extending the odoo8 hr_recruitment module, and i need to show a list of applicants of a job. But when i'm going to access the form view of hr.job i get this error:

**domain = domain + [(inverse, 'in', ids)]
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects**

Mi code is this:

```
class hr_job(osv.osv):
_inherit = "hr.job"
_name = "hr.job"
_inherits = {'mail.alias': 'alias_id'}

def _get_attached_docs(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    attachment_obj = self.pool.get('ir.attachment')
    for job_id in ids:
        applicant_ids = self.pool.get('hr.applicant').search(cr, uid, [('job_id', '=', job_id)], context=context)
        res[job_id] = attachment_obj.search(
            cr, uid, [
                '|',
                '&', ('res_model', '=', 'hr.job'), ('res_id', '=', job_id),
                '&', ('res_model', '=', 'hr.applicant'), ('res_id', 'in', applicant_ids)
            ], context=context)
    return res

def _count_all(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    Applicant = self.pool['hr.applicant']
    return {
        job_id: {
            'application_count': Applicant.search_count(cr, uid, [('job_id', '=', job_id)], context=context),
            'documents_count': len(self._get_attached_docs(cr, uid, [job_id], field_name, arg, context=context)[job_id])
        }
        for job_id in ids
    }

_columns = {
    'survey_id': fields.many2one('survey.survey', 'Interview Form', help="Choose an interview form for this job position and you will be able to print/answer this interview from all applicants who apply for this job"),
    'alias_id': fields.many2one('mail.alias', 'Alias', ondelete="restrict", required=True,
                                help="Email alias for this job position. New emails will automatically "
                                     "create new applicants for this job position."),
    'address_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Job Location', help="Address where employees are working"),
    'application_ids': fields.one2many('hr.applicant', 'job_id', 'Applications'),
    'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Cliente'),
    'application_count': fields.function(_count_all, type='integer', string='Applications', multi=True),
    'manager_id': fields.related('department_id', 'manager_id', type='many2one', string='Department Manager', relation='hr.employee', readonly=True, store=True),
    'document_ids': fields.function(_get_attached_docs, type='one2many', relation='ir.attachment', string='Applications'),
    'documents_count': fields.function(_count_all, type='integer', string='Documents', multi=True),
    'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Recruitment Responsible', track_visibility='onchange'),
    'color': fields.integer('Color Index'),
    'responsable_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Responsable'),
    'estado': fields.selection([(u'No Iniciado', u'No Iniciado'),
                                (u'En Proceso', u'En Proceso'),
                                (u'Contratado(a)', u'Contratado(a)'),
                                (u'Suspendido', u'Suspendido'),
                                (u'Finalizado', u'Finalizado'),
                                ('Otro', 'Otro')], 'Estado del Proceso'),
    'otro': fields.char('Otro Estado'),
    'fecha_inicio': fields.date('Fecha Inicio'),
    'fecha_fin': fields.date('Fecha Fin'),
    'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Cliente'),
    'applicant_ids': fields.one2many('hr.applicant', 'job_id', 'Candidatos', domain="[('partner_id','=',partner_id)]"),
```

I think the problem is on domain of applicant_ids...

How can i solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change field domain to a list:

```
'applicant_ids': fields.one2many('hr.applicant', 
                                 'job_id', 
                                 'Candidatos', 
                                  domain=[('partner_id','=',partner_id)])
```

You can check this answer [Understanding OpenERP domain filter?](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/understanding-openerp-domain-filter-58405)
or
The documentation for [domains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#domains)